# JS Regex solution to turn reddit style links into html?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

As practice I was trying to recreate reddits formatting conventions found here
https://www.reddit.com/r/raerth/comments/cw70q/reddit_comment_formatting/

I got stuck on reddit style links. 
this is a link

Here's what I got

```
\[.*\]\(https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+)

[fefoefoeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTpcy7EGPYY&list=PL5zJAQW9sgyRNOP6r6i0Ww3dNTE9X1sQq&index=4)
```

More specifically, I am trying to convert the text above into this:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JTpcy7EGPYY4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I got

> [fefoefoeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTpcy7EGPYY

highlighted but I am stumped as to how I highlight the rest. I am trying to use string replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

but this is very new to me and I don't even understand what to do once I HAVE highlighted the stuff to be changed.

Comment: Why are you matching the stuff in the initial `[...]` brackets if you only need the youtube link? Match the youtube link, then concatenate it into that `<iframe` string

Comment: I would like to replace the [...] stuff too because I wanted to make two versions of this script, a youtube one and a regular link one. if I know how the youtube one works (the harder one), it will help me make the regular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, https://regexr.com combined with https://txt2re.com/ helped a lot. It's actually really simple with some grouping and some wildcards.